# Browning cubes in a saute pan - when have at least N sides of all cubes been browned?

Tags: probability, problem-solving

Thought of this mathematics puzzle while cooking cubes of tofu the other day. It sounds like a probability problem, but I am not getting anywhere. The puzzle:

You're cooking C cubes of something in a pan to brown them. It's not necessary to brown all sides of all cubes, but you want to brown at least N sides of all cubes. Cube sides are considered "browned" when they spend at least SB seconds on the bottom, in contact with the pan. Every SS seconds you shake the pan to arbitrarily rearrange the cubes' orientations. By counting only the number of browned cube sides facing up, B, what is the minimum B/C that will allow you to be 95% (say) confident that all cubes have at least N sides browned.

---

I'm a PhD engineer turned IT so have a fair amount of mathematics background. Probability is not one of my strong suits, however.

Comment: I don't quite understand. How would it be possible to guarantee the other sides (if $N>1$) are browned only by looking at the top sides?

Comment: Is $SB$ bigger or smaller than $SS$? I think the problem is easier if $SS \geq SB$.

Comment: Since all cubes are equivalent and independent, I think the problem can be simplified by looking at just one cube. Say that every $S$ seconds one of the six sides is chosen at random to be browned, with repetition allowed. After $M$ flips, what is the distribution of the number of sides which are browned? This problem will boil down to questions like "How many ways are there to distribute $M$ identical objects among $6$ identical buckets?"

Comment: Does the distribution actually matter here? We’re looking for when it’s “guarenteed”. If you see $B$, then you can only guarantee $B$ if you just flipped or $B+C$ if you’ve just waited more than $SB$.  If you just want to be reasonably confident, you can get something like a Binomial distribution where you can calculate the exact prior distribution a given face is browned depending on the exact details, get the distribution for the side faces and then add in the known top (and maybe bottom) faces.

Comment: @legionwhale - Yes, my word choice of "guaranteed" was not appropriate. I should have said "with 95% certainty" or something along those lines.

Comment: @JohnBarber - I included those times to make it more general. I think a good approximation is to let SS = SB. That means, you let the bottom sides brown before flipping.

I had thought about looking at a single cube, but had over-thunked it, I think. I will go back and re-think that approach. Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: @Eric - Agreed. "Guaranteed" was a poor word choice. And that's another "given" I hadn't thought about. If you wait for the bottom side to get fully browned, you then have information about 2 of the sides. Thank you.